# Using temporary tables in ssis package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012

i have a problem - I want to use temp table in stored procedure is SQL Server, which will be executed from SSIS package.
I read some tips how to do it and I tried this one (first answer): [Using Temp tables in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579476/using-temp-tables-in-ssis)
but it didn't work.
I have MS Visual Studio 2010, couldn't be problem with this version? 
Here is my code in stored proc.:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure      
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT CAST(NULL AS int) as number
END
CREATE TABLE #some_table (number int)
INSERT INTO #some_table VALUES (250)
SELECT number FROM #some_table
```

Thanks for any advice or experience.

Here is error message from Visual Studio:

> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The
>   metadata could not be determined because statement 'INSERT INTO
>    #some_table VALUES (250)' in procedure 'some_procedure' uses a temp table.".
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: Unable to retrieve column
>   information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the
>   database is available.

Comment: Are you having problem getting the meta data? If so you need to set `SET FMTONLY ON` in design to get the meta data and then remove after design to get the data. [Here is information to use FMTONLY to get meta data](http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/set-fmtonly-on-useful-in-tsql-ssis-packages-for-using-temp-tables/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012 if you use temporary tables you must specify a results set.

This is an issue with the sp_describe_first_result_set procedure that SSIS uses to returns the output metadata.

E.g.

```
EXEC dbo.RptResults_StoredProcedure
```

Becomes

```
EXEC dbo.RptResults_StoredProcedure
WITH RESULT SETS
((
    Date NVARCHAR(10),
    Location VARCHAR(12),
    Department CHAR(1),
    Shift CHAR(1),
    ForecastSales DECIMAL(18,2),
    ActualSales DECIMAL(18,2)
))
```

For more information  view

http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2014/08/22/column-metadata-determined-correctly-ssis-data-flow-task-stored-procedure-inputs/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of temp table you can use table variable or cte... these don't have the issue like temp table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE some_procedure      
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare @some_table TABLE (number int)
INSERT INTO @some_table VALUES (250)
SELECT number FROM @some_table
```