# Stored procedure taking long time when it runs through SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have a below procedure which uses 3 temp tables and finally insert into a table. I am using below sp as source (execute sql task) and loading into csv files. When i run this sp from SSMS it runs within 10 seconds, but when I Put into SSIS package it runs for 30 mins and keep on running. Could any of you optimize this SP for SSIS package?

```
create proc [etl].[payment_report]
       @start_date datetime,
       @end_date datetime
as
begin
    truncate table extract.payment

    select
        a.bb_acct_id, a.customer_id,
        pay.order_id Payment_Order_Id,
        aoi.ord_prod_id Ord_Prod_Id,
        pd.name, pd.quick_cd
    into 
        #IntialOrders
    from
        (select * 
         from stg.payment (NOLOCK)
         where order_id is not null) pay
    inner join 
        stg.account a (NOLOCK) on pay.acct_id = a.acct_id
    inner join 
        stg.acct_order ao (NOLOCK) on ao.order_id = pay.order_id
    inner join 
        stg.acct_order_item aoi (NOLOCK) on aoi.order_id = ao.order_id
    inner join 
        stg.ordered_product op (NOLOCK) on op.ord_prod_id = aoi.ord_prod_id
    left join 
        stg.product p (NOLOCK) on p.prod_id = op.prod_id
    left join 
        stg.product_def pd (NOLOCK) on pd.prod_def_id = p.prod_def_id
    where 
        pay.received_date >= @start_date
        and pay.received_date < @end_date
        and pay.payment_id not in (select payment_id 
                                   from stg.op_renewal_history)

    create clustered index Idx_Payment_Order_Id on #IntialOrders(Payment_Order_Id)

     select
         pay.payment_id, gwr.response
     into 
         #gateway_response
     from  
         stg.payment pay (NOLOCK)
     inner join 
         stg.cc_transactions cct (NOLOCK) on cct.payment_id = pay.payment_id
     inner join 
         stg.gateway_response gwr (NOLOCK) on cct.c_c_trans_id = gwr.cc_trans_id
     where
         pay.posting_status_id = 3
         and pay.received_date >= @start_date
         and pay.received_date < @end_date
         and pay.received_date > '2015-04-15 00:00:00'

     select

                     distinct a.bb_acct_id SP_ACCOUNT_ID

                     ,a.customer_id CP_CUSTOMER_ID

                     ,bu.description BUSINESS_UNIT

                     ,pay.payment_id PAYMENT_ID

                     ,pay.payment_amt  AMOUNT

                     ,'SEK' CURRENCY

                     ,Substring(convert(char(19),pay.received_date,126), 1, (len(convert(char(19),pay.received_date,126))-0))+'Z' PAYMENT_DATE

                     ,pt.display_name PAYMENT_METHOD

                     ,post.description PAYMENT_STATUS

                     ,pay.retries PAYMENT_RETRIES

                     ,case when (pay.for_bill_id is not null or orh.op_id is not null) then 'Renewal' else 'OneTime' end as PAYMENT_TYPE

                     ,case when pay.posting_status_id =3  then gwr.response else '' end as FAILURE_REASON

                     ,case when op.ord_prod_id is null then ino.name else pd.name end SUBSCRIPTION_NAME

                     ,case when op.ord_prod_id is null then ino.quick_cd else pd.quick_cd end  SKU

                     ,case when op.ord_prod_id is null then ino.Ord_Prod_Id else op.ord_prod_id end  ORD_PROD_ID

                     ,convert(char(19),GETDATE(),126)+'Z' EXPORT_TIME

                     ,case when  (pay.posting_status_id =3 and pay.retries = 3 ) then 'T' else 'F' end FAILED_EXTENDED_RETRY

         into #payment

         from stg.payment pay (NOLOCK)

                     left join #IntialOrders ino (NOLOCK) on

                                  ino.Payment_Order_Id=pay.order_id

                     left join stg.account a (NOLOCK) on 

                                  a.acct_id = pay.acct_id

                     left join stg.business_unit bu (NOLOCK) on

                                  a.bu_id=bu.bu_id

                     left join stg.payment_method pm (NOLOCK) on

                                  pm.pay_method_id=pay.payment_method_id

                     left join stg.payment_type pt (NOLOCK) on

                                  pt.id=pm.type_id

                     left join stg.posting_status post (NOLOCK) on

                                  post.id=pay.posting_status_id

                     left join stg.op_renewal_history orh (NOLOCK) on

                                  orh.payment_id = pay.payment_id

                     left join stg.ordered_product op (NOLOCK) on

                                  op.ord_prod_id = orh.op_id

                     left join stg.product p (NOLOCK) on

                                  p.prod_id = op.prod_id

            left join stg.product_def pd (NOLOCK) on

                           pd.prod_def_id = p.prod_def_id

                     left join #gateway_reponse gwr (NOLOCK) on

                           gwr.payment_id = pay.payment_id

              where

                     a.bu_id=1

                     and (a.acct_role_id is null or a.acct_role_id !=4)

                     and (pay.posting_status_id=2 or (pay.posting_status_id =3

                     and pay.retries = 3

                     and op.acct_status_id=3))

                     and pay.received_date >=@start_date

                     and pay.received_date < @end_date

                     and pay.received_date > '2015-04-15 00:00:00'





         insert into extract.payment

                     (

                         SP_ACCOUNT_ID

                           ,CP_CUSTOMER_ID

                           ,BUSINESS_UNIT

                           ,PAYMENT_ID

                           ,AMOUNT

                           ,CURRENCY

                           ,PAYMENT_DATE

                           ,PAYMENT_METHOD

                           ,PAYMENT_STATUS

                           ,PAYMENT_RETRIES

                           ,PAYMENT_TYPE

                           ,FAILURE_REASON

                           ,SUBSCRIPTION_NAME

                           ,SKU,ORD_PROD_ID

                           ,EXPORT_TIME

                           ,FAILED_EXTENDED_RETRY

                     )



            select

                         cast(p.SP_ACCOUNT_ID  as varchar(50)) SP_ACCOUNT_ID

                           ,cast(p.CP_CUSTOMER_ID  as varchar(50)) CP_CUSTOMER_ID

                           ,cast(p.BUSINESS_UNIT as varchar(500)) BUSINESS_UNIT

                           ,cast( p.PAYMENT_ID as varchar(50)) PAYMENT_ID, p.AMOUNT

                           ,cast( p.CURRENCY as varchar(50)) CURRENCY

                           ,cast( p.PAYMENT_DATE as varchar(50)) PAYMENT_DATE

                           ,cast( p.PAYMENT_METHOD as varchar(50)) PAYMENT_METHOD

                           ,cast(p.PAYMENT_STATUS as varchar(50)) PAYMENT_STATUS

                           ,cast( p.PAYMENT_RETRIES as varchar(50)) PAYMENT_RETRIES

                           ,cast(p.PAYMENT_TYPE as varchar(50)) PAYMENT_TYPE

                           ,cast( p.FAILURE_REASON as varchar(4000)) FAILURE_REASON

                           ,cast(p.SUBSCRIPTION_NAME as varchar(500)) SUBSCRIPTION_NAME

                           ,cast(p.SKU as varchar(50)) SKU

                           ,cast(p.ORD_PROD_ID as varchar(50)) ORD_PROD_ID

                           ,cast( p.EXPORT_TIME as varchar(50)) EXPORT_TIME

                           ,p.FAILED_EXTENDED_RETRY



              from #payment p



              order by p.PAYMENT_DATE



              Drop table #IntialOrders

              Drop table #gateway_reponse

              Drop table #payment





       END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Temp tables in SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579476/using-temp-tables-in-ssis)

Comment: As this looks like a financial application you probably should stop using the NOLOCK hint unless you are ok with inaccurate results. It is MUCH more than just dirty reads. It can and will return missing and/or duplicate rows in addition to many other unsavory things. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Why don't you use SSIS for real? ETL package is supposed to do all the things you implemented in this SP. SSIS can do not only SP calls.