# How to EXEC a stored procedure from SSIS to get its output to text file

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis, sql-server-2012

I wrote a stored procedure that reads records into a temp table and then creates a pivoted output from the data in the temp table.

Running the stored procedure from SSMS works just fine. What I am facing problems is now that I am trying to create the SSIS package that will execute the sproc, and write its output to a tab delimited text file.

I am using Visual Studio 2015. My first problem is that when I try to configure the OLE DB Source within the Data Flow Task, when adding the SQL Command inside the SQL Command Text box: EXEC ShopperSkuHistory and click OK, I get this error:

[image]

I have been looking for information about this error, but I have not found anything that helps me understand why this is happening, and how I can fix it.

I hope through this post I can learn how to fix this error.

Thank you much in advance.

Here is my sproc:

**UPDATED CODE**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ShopperSkuHistory]

AS
BEGIN

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..[#ShopperSku_History_Load]') IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                        DROP TABLE [#ShopperSku_History_Load];
                END;        

        -- Create main table
        CREATE TABLE [#ShopperSku_History_Load]
        (
            [ID]                                    INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL
        ,   [shopper_id]    CHAR(32) NOT NULL
        ,   [sku]                               VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL                       
        , time_added  DATETIME      
        )       

        SET NOCOUNT ON; 

        -- Populate the table 
        INSERT INTO [#ShopperSku_History_Load] ([shopper_id], [sku], [time_added])      
        SELECT DISTINCT [cr].[shopper_id], LEFT([cri].[sku], 9) [sku], GETDATE() [time_added]
        FROM [dbo].[receipt_item] [cri]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[receipt] [cr]
                ON [cri].[order_id] = [cr].[order_id]
        WHERE[cri].[list_price] > 0
                AND [cri].[IsInitialPurchase] = 1
                AND LEFT([cri].[sku], 3) = 'MN0'
                AND ([cr].[date_entered] > DATEADD(YEAR, -2, GETDATE()))
                AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [product] [cp] WHERE [cp].[pf_id] = [cri].[sku] AND [cp].[for_sale] = 1)
                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[shopper] [cs] WHERE [cs].[IsTesting] = 1 AND [cs].[shopper_bounce] = [cr].[shopper_id])                
        ORDER BY [shopper_id];  

        CREATE TABLE [#HistoryOutput] 
        (
        [shopper_id] VARCHAR(32)
        , skus TEXT
        )

        INSERT INTO [#HistoryOutput]
        ( [shopper_id], [skus] )        

        SELECT
            [shopper_id]
        , STUFF(( SELECT ', ' + ISNULL([a].[sku], '')
                                                            FROM [#ShopperSku_History_Load] [a]
                                                            WHERE [a].[shopper_id] = [b].[shopper_id]
                                                                FOR
                                                                        XML PATH('')
                                                        ), 1, 1, '') [skus]
    FROM [#ShopperSku_History_Load] [b]
        GROUP BY [shopper_id];

    SELECT
        [shopper_id]
      , [skus]
    FROM
        [#HistoryOutput];

END;
```

**UPDATED ERROR**

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0202009
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Incorrect syntax near 'shopper_id'.".
```

Comment: Sorry, I can not see the image. Can you paste the error in the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error

> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC
>   XXXXXX'  in procedure 'XXXXXX' contains dynamic SQL.
>   Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the
>   result set.

happens because the SP contains either a

1. Temp table
2. Dynamic SQL

Because of these dynamic elements, SSIS/SSDT has trouble getting the column metadata correctly. More info [here](https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/column-metadata-determined-correctly-ssis-data-flow-task-stored-procedure-inputs).  We need to help SSIS get that column metadata. Depending on your SQL Server version, there are two solutions.

[image]

For SSIS/SQL 2008, you can try setting `FMTONLY OFF`
[image]

For SSIS/SQL 2012, you can wrap the stored procedure with a `RESULT SET` from SSIS.  Try this ...

[image]

Other options include updating the Stored Procedure itself and adding a `WITH RESULTS SETS` clause.  Or updating the stored procedure to return a table variable.

Comment: Hi Troy, I am using VS/SSIS 2015, and SQL 2012. I am a bit unsure how to update the stored procedure. to add WITH RESULTS SETS.

Comment: I tried your recommendation, unsure if I am doing it right. Still get an error although a different one. I have updated my code and the error text.

Comment: Your new error is a Syntax error.  The SP is now broken.  Try it in SSMS and see if it works.  Please revert it back and look at the update to my answer.  Add the `RESULT SET` clause in SSIS, thanks.

Comment: `[shopper_id]    CHAR(32)`..Is this valid ? Replace CHAR with VARCHAR and run your sp.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft:  wrapping the stored procedure with a RESULT SET from SSIS did fix my issue, and now I am able to run the package with the expected results. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Great to hear.  Glad you have it sorted out!   Good luck with your project.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft Hi Troy, I have a SP taking 2 input and 1 output parameters. It returns a result set. When i did the above changes as mentioned in your answer, it is now giving me a different error : "No value given for one or more required parameters". The SP call is as `EXEC [uspName] @startDate, @EndDate, Average OUTPUT` in SSMS. In the result set, it gives 3 columns `[WeekStartDate] DATETIME, [Average] DECIMAL(5,2), [pln] VARCAHR(5)` Do you have any inputs about what may be causing this?

Comment: @ArpitChinmay It sounds like your issue revolves around the use of the `output parameters`?  That is different from OPs question.  Please open a new question for that. Provide all of the details.  As a guess, you probably need to use the `Execute SQL` component and use parameter mapping and variables to capture that output.  Have a look here = https://www.sqlshack.com/execute-sql-tasks-in-ssis-output-parameters-vs-result-sets/

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft I already used the Execute SQL Task and it ran fine. I was unable to find any article that would guide me to store the values from the result set parameter to Excel file. I have now made a For each container with a data flow taskin it. It executes the SP in OLE DB source and tries to store result in excel destination. I would like to point that, the problem was not in OLE DB source, it was in the Excel destination. My packages stores the value in CSV file correctly.